# If $E$ is algebraic extension field of $F$, then also $E(x)$ is algebraic extension of $F(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, transcendence-degree

I had a so simple question.

> **Question:** Let $E$ be an algebraic extension field of a field $F$.  Does it follow that $E(x)$ is an algebraic extension field of $F(x)$?

I think it is not true  and i can easily take counter example.

umm.. but i can't take one.

What's the example one?

Comment: Should $E(x)$ be an algebraic extension of $E$?

Comment: You should put the full question within the body as well, not just the title.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is algebraic over $E$, then $x$ is also algebraic over $F$ since $E$ is an algebraic extension over $F$.  Therefore $E(x)$ is algebraic over $F$.  This shows that $E(x)$ is algebraic over $F(x)$ as well.

If $x$ is transcendent over $E$, then you should read up on *transcendence degree*.  Write $\text{tr-deg}_K(L)$ for the transcendence degree of a field extension $L$ over a field $K$.  Then, for a tower of fields $M\geq L\geq K$, we have
$$\text{tr-deg}_K(M)=\text{tr-deg}_L(M)+\text{tr-deg}_K(L)$$
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134234/transcendence-degree-of-a-field-extension)).  Thus,
$$\text{tr-deg}_F\big(E(x)\big)=\text{tr-deg}_E\big(E(x)\big)+\text{tr-deg}_F(E)=1+0=1\,,$$
as $E$ is algebraic over $F$.  On the other hand,
$$\text{tr-deg}_F\big(E(x)\big)=\text{tr-deg}_{F(x)}\big(E(x)\big)+\text{tr-deg}_F\big(F(x)\big)=\text{tr-deg}_{F(x)}\big(E(x)\big)+1\,,$$
as $x$ is transcendent over $F$ as well.  This shows that
$$\text{tr-deg}_{F(x)}\big(E(x)\big)=0\,,$$
whence $E(x)$ is an algebraic extension of $F(x)$.

Comment: Very Good! Thank you so much!! : )