# If E is a finite algebraic extension of K, prove E(x) is finite algebraic extension of K(x)

Tags: field-theory

I am trying to prove the following question:
Let $K$ be a field with $E$ finite algebraic extension of $K$, $\tilde{E}=E(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $\tilde{K}=K(x_1,...,x_n)$ (fields of quotients of polynomials). Prove that $\tilde{E}$ is a finite algebraic extension of $\tilde{K}$. I'm trying to proceed by induction, so I need to answer the question on the title.

I am having trouble proving this because the field of quotients of polynomials really confuses me, and I'm having a hard time trying to find a basis of E(x).

I found the question here [If $E$ is algebraic extension field of $F$, then also $E(x)$ is algebraic extension of $F(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934125/if-e-is-algebraic-extension-field-of-f-then-also-ex-is-algebraic-extens) however, the answer there uses "trascendence degree", a topic not covered in class.

Any hints are appreciated

Comment: Hint. Consider a special case when $E = K(a)$. Prove that in such case $\tilde{E} = \tilde{K}(a)$. By induction on the number of generators of $E$ over $K$ reduce the problem to the special case.